# Animate filling in an SVG cloud icon from left to right

Tags: css, animation, svg

Im trying to animate filling in a cloud from LEFT to RIGHT (kind of like a progress bar) using an SVG cloud.  Here is the cloud:

```
  %svg{:height => "80", :version => "1.1", :viewbox => "0 0 120 80", :width => "120", :xmlns => "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "xmlns:figma" => "http://www.figma.com/figma/ns", "xmlns:xlink" => "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"}
    %title Vector
    %g#Canvas{"figma:type" => "canvas", :transform => "translate(1558 -2264)"}
      %g#Vector{"figma:type" => "vector", :style => "mix-blend-mode:normal;"}
        %use{:style => "mix-blend-mode:normal;", :transform => "translate(-1558 2264)", "xlink:href" => "#path0_fill"}
        %use{:fill => "#FFFFFF", :style => "mix-blend-mode:normal;", :transform => "translate(-1558 2264)", "xlink:href" => "#path0_fill"}
    %defs
      %path#path0_fill{:d => "M 96.775 30.175C 93.375 12.975 78.2 0 60
```

I tried creating an animated gradient but that didnt really work.  Does anyone have any idea how I can animate an outline of this SVG that fills up from left to right for a given duration?  Im open to using CSS or JS to make it happen.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I believe I figured it out, but when the page loads half the cloud is loaded.

```
%svg{:height => "104", :version => "1.1", :viewbox => "0 0 144 104", :width => "144", :xmlns => "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "xmlns:figma" => "http://www.figma.com/figma/ns", "xmlns:xlink" => "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"}
  %g#Canvas{"figma:type" => "canvas", :transform => "translate(1570 -2256)"}
    %g#ic_cloud_48px{"figma:type" => "frame", :filter => "url(#filter0_d)", :style => "mix-blend-mode:normal;"}
      %g#Vector{"figma:type" => "vector", :style => "mix-blend-mode:normal;"}
        %use{:fill => "#ffffff", opacity: '1', :style => "mix-blend-mode:normal;", :transform => "translate(-1558 2264)", "xlink:href" => "#path0_fill"}
  %defs
    %lineargradient#half_grad{x1: 0}
      %stop{:offset => "50%", "stop-color" => "white"}
      %stop{:offset => "50%", "stop-opacity" => "0"}
      %animate{:attributename => "x1", :dur => "60s", :from => "-100%", :to => "100%", fill: "freeze"}

    %filter#filter0_d{"color-interpolation-filters" => "sRGB", :filterunits => "userSpaceOnUse", :height => "104", :width => "144", :x => "-1570", :y => "2256"}
      %feflood{"flood-opacity" => "0", :result => "BackgroundImageFix"}
      %desc type="dropShadow" x="0" y="4" size="12" spread="0" color="0,0.498652,0.660377,0.24" blend="normal"
      %fecolormatrix{:in => "SourceAlpha", :type => "matrix", :values => "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 255 0"}
      %feoffset{:dx => "0", :dy => "4"}
      %fegaussianblur{:stddeviation => "6"}
      %fecolormatrix{:type => "matrix", :values => "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.498652 0 0 0 0 0.660377 0 0 0 0.24 0"}
      %feblend{:in2 => "BackgroundImageFix", :mode => "normal", :result => "effect1_dropShadow"}
      %feblend{:in => "SourceGraphic", :in2 => "effect1_dropShadow", :mode => "normal", :result => "shape"}
    %path#path0_fill{fill: "url(#half_grad)", 'stroke-width' => "3", stroke: "white", :d => "M 96.775 30.175C 93.375 12.975 78.2 0 60 0C 45.55 0 33.025 8.2 26.75 20.175C 11.725 21.8 0 34.525 0 50C 0 66.575 13.425 80 30 80L 95 80C 108.8 80 120 68.8 120 55C 120 41.8 109.725 31.1 96.775 30.175Z"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in your linear gradient and how you are animating it.

```
%lineargradient#half_grad{x1: 0}
  %stop{:offset => "50%", "stop-color" => "white"}
  %stop{:offset => "50%", "stop-opacity" => "0"}
  %animate{:attributename => "x1", :dur => "60s", :from => "-100%", :to => "100%", fill: "freeze"}
```

You are animating the `x1` of your gradient up to 100%, but your gradient is defined to change halfway across (at 50%).  If you want the colour change at 50% to coincide with the right hand side of your cloud, you should animate up to 200%.

Ie. the following is (probably) what you want:

```
%animate{:attributename => "x1", :dur => "60s", :from => "0%", :to => "200%", fill: "freeze"}
```

Comment: Thanks.  What I am trying to do is slowly fill the SVG from left to right with white, hence the 50% offset.  Should the offset be set to something else to accomplish this effect?

Comment: 50% should work. It just means that to get your colour switch to finish at the right side (100%), you'll need `x1` to animate up to `200%`.